# Is it possible to use Ext.Resizable on a 'width: 100%' element?

Tags: extjs, textarea

When I apply `Ext.Resizable` with parameters `wrap: true, handles: 's'` to an `Ext.form.TextArea` with `width: 100%`, the text area loses its width.  More specifically, the width is reset to sth. like default width in pixels.  Is it possible to cleanly make `Ext.Resizable` just not touch width at all and operate on element's height only?  I checked that not touching width would work fine in principle by replacing (in FireBug) explicit widths on the text area and wrapping `div` back with 'width: 100%'.

I'm trying to achieve effect similar to SO's question/answer text area, which can be resized for height.

Comment: @artlung: I eventually worked around this by using a hackish subclass of `Ext.Resizable`.  If you are interested, I can retrieve it and paste here.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't anchoring an option, with `layout:'fit'` on a panel and `anchor:'100%'` on the textarea the width should stay at 100%.

The drawback is that you are required to wrap everything in a panel and possibly also use ext components (like Ext.form.Textarea)

ref: http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/anchoring.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var el = Ext.getBody().createChild({
        tag: 'div',
        style: 'width: 600px;'
    });

    var area = new Ext.form.TextArea({
        renderTo: el,
        style: 'width: 100%'
    });

    new Ext.Resizable(area.el, {
        wrap: true,
        handles: 's',
        height: area.getHeight(),

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my hackish subclass I eventually used.

```
ExtOverrideUtils = {
    setSizeIgnoreWidth: function (width, height, animate)
    {
        this.setHeight ((typeof width == 'object' ? width.height : height), animate);
    },

    intercept: function (func, overrides)
    {
        return function ()
            {
                var  value = func.apply (this, arguments);

                if (value) {
                    for (var name in overrides)
                        value[name] = overrides[name];
                }

                return value;
            };
    }
}

NoWidthResizable = Ext.extend (Ext.Resizable,
    {
        constructor: function (el, config)
        {
            el = Ext.get (el);

            el.setSize = ExtOverrideUtils.setSizeIgnoreWidth;
            el.wrap    = ExtOverrideUtils.intercept (el.wrap, { setSize: ExtOverrideUtils.setSizeIgnoreWidth });

            NoWidthResizable.superclass.constructor.call (this, el, config);
        }
    });
```

Usage from a custom subclass of `Ext.form.TextArea` (though I guess it can be used just as normal `Ext.Resizable`, for arbitrary element):

```
this._resizer = new NoWidthResizable (this.el,
                                      { wrap: true,
                                        handles: 's',
                                        minHeight: 30,
                                        pinned: true,
                                        dynamic: true });
```